# Eliminar archivos y carpetas temporales cuando se presente un error C#

Tags: c#, eliminar

estoy creando un .zip, hago uso de carpetas temporales que guardan los archivos para que después de generar el zip eliminarlas y no llenar el Temp de carpetas por descarga que se haga.
Ahora necesito que cuando haya algún error al crear un PDF (que es lo que guarda mi zip) todos los archivos y carpetas que sí se lograron crear se eliminen para que el Temp no quede con carpetas y archivos que no se eliminaron porque no se pudo realizar la descarga.
¿De qué manera puedo realizar esa eliminación?

Dejo el código que uso para crear el zip y eliminar los temporales.

```
                                //Creación del .zip
                                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(rutaZip, pathZip);
                                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathZip);
                                string mimeName = MimeExtensionHelper.GetMimeType(zip);

                                //Apertura y lectura de fileInfo para recuperar en un byte[]
                                byte[] buffer;

                                FileStream fS = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open);
                                try
                                {
                                    int length = (int)fS.Length;
                                    buffer = new byte[length];
                                    int count;
                                    int sum = 0;

                                    while ((count = fS.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                                    sum += count;

                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    fS.Close();
                                }

                                //Eliminación de archivos y carpetas temporales 
                                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                                {
                                    Directory.Delete(path, true);
                                }
                                return File(buffer, mimeName, fileInfo.Name);
```

Comment: En tu Try añades un CATH y ahí eliminas cuando hay error. Pero quizas lo mejor sea que borres en el finally asi siempre eliminas tus temporales

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: @Irais en la parte inferior, existe una área de texto que dice "Tu respuesta", por favor, úsala para agregar lo que hiciste por efecto del comentario del buen usuario Yussef. De ese modo, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo escenario o uno similar, al mismo tiempo colaboras con la buena salud del sitio por efecto de preguntas resueltas y mejor aún si marcas esa respuesta como aceptada. Saludos.